# Fetching data from more than 2 tables using EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a method that returns data from more than 2 tables, there is no mapping relation between those tables.

```
Public class UserInfo
{
  public string UserName {get; set;}  //UserTable
  public string UserMail { get; set;} //UserTable
  public string ServiceName {get; set;} //ServiceTable
  public string Specialization {get; set;}  //SpecializationTable
}

public UserInfo fetchUserInfo(int userId)
{


}
```

what is the best way i can get those records ServiceName and Specialization ?

Comment: you will end up selecting all records of that table if you don't have any mapping

Comment: is it not possible to select single value using the same UserId ?

Comment: what is the definition of this class `UserTable`? can you show it also?

Comment: It has ID(its a primary key), UserId(int), UserMail, CIty, Department, Mobile fields

Comment: so what is the relationship of servnice name and usertable? does service name contains a column that is mapped to user id so when I select on this table i will just say? servicename.userid = usrInfo.userid???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm suggest you to use "join" to solve this issue.

It would be something like.

```
from userTable in SBDB.UserTable
join serviceTable in SBDB.ServiceTable on userTable.ID equals serviceTable.ID
join specializationTable in SBDB.SpecializationTable on .....
where ....
select new PO_Master {
   UserName = usrInfo.UserName;
    UserMail = usrInfo.UserEmail;
    ServiceName = serviceTable.ServiceName;// need to get this from service table
    Specialization = specializationTable.Specialization;// need to get this from specialization table
}
```

Hope this help.